# How to encrypt public key with rc4 in openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa, rc4-cipher

I have found [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Public_Key_Cryptographic_Operations) way of generating rsa public key with openssl and encrypting it with aes:

**openssl genrsa -aes256 -out public.pem 4096**

how could i do the same with rc4:

`openssl genrsa -rc4 -out public.pem 4096`

`Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus
...............................................................................................................................++
...............................++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
140272337293760:error:09069071:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_write_bio:unsupported cipher:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:309:`

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are using generates a RSA key pair (private and public) and not a public key. Encrypting a public key usually doesn't make sense, because it should be public.

If you want to encrypt the key pair, OpenSSL doesn't support RC4 for PEM encryption, but you can encrypt the key file, using openssl encryption.

```
openssl rc4 -in keypair.pem -out keypair.enc -pbkdf2
```

If you want to use the keys, you'll have to decrypt them:

```
openssl rc4 -d -in keypair.enc -out keypair.pem -pbkdf2
```

Note that pbkdf2 option is recommended but not mandatory. Also, pbkdf2 is supported only in the latest OpenSSL version, 1.1.1, if you are using a older version, you have to drop the option.

```
openssl rc4 -in keypair.enc -out keypair.pem
```

If you really want to encrypt a public key, you'll have to extract the public key from the key pair:

```
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -out pub.pem -pubout
```

And encrypt it:

```
openssl rc4 -in pub.pem -out pub.enc -pbkdf2
```

Comment: Mostly concur, and welcome, but: `enc -pbkdf2` is only in 1.1.1 released 2 months ago; many environments (distros etc) aren't that fast so you may need to build yourself. Without `-pbkdf2` or in lower versions it uses EVP_BytesToKey with 1 iteration which is bad -- but no worse than legacy-PEM encryption. For `pkcs12 -export` the option is `-nocerts` (with s), but `-rc4` (or any `-cipher`) applies only to _import_ i.e. P12-to-PEM; it is ignored for export. The export option is `-keypbe cipher` and that fails for rc4, just like `pkcs8 -topk8` and `pkey` and `genpkey` do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right. I updated the answer to remove the pkcs#12 and explain the pbkdf2 option.